# Cannot send keys to a specific input type="tel" with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to fill a form with Selenium, all the inputs are filled but one is ignored.
This is the input I am trying to fill:

```
<input type="text" name="MAIN_DRIVER_DATE_OF_BIRTH" value="12/15/1990" class="form-control form-control-danger col-md-6" maxlength="10" placeholder="JJ/MM/AAAA" label="">
```

I've tried using this code :

```
            date_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name("MAIN_DRIVER_DATE_OF_BIRTH")
            date_input.send_keys("19/12/1990")
```

but it didn't work.

It does work on Selenium IDE Chrome extension but when I export the same code and try it, it wouldn't work.

Selenium version: 3.141.0 Chrome version: 80.0.3987.122

Comment: I think without more information about the runtime environment or a complete example, it will be impossible for someone to help you. You should also add that you are using (i guess) using the Python language bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
It was resolved by performing a click() action on date_input before performing the send_keys() action.

In your case it could also be because the date_input field is expecting input in "mm/dd/yyyy" format and you are sending it in "dd/mm/yyyy" format.

Try `date_input.send_keys("12/19/1990")`instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you copying only specific lines from test case exported from Selenium IDE in chrome? If yes, IDE might be recording additional action just before the line:

```
date_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name("MAIN_DRIVER_DATE_OF_BIRTH")
        date_input.send_keys("19/12/1990")
```

Please check that and copy that action too.

OR

try using

```
driver.click()
```

before

date_input.send_keys("19/12/1990")

Answer (score 0):

```
tel = driver.find_element_by_id("tel-input")
for i in range(1,10):
    tel.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
tel.send_keys(444444444)
```

Enter the input id you want to input data into instead of "tel-input"

Make a backspace up to the starting point of the input.

This equates to 9 times in my example

and Done!

> This method is not very good in my opinion, but we need to use it